# How to conditionally output a year when showing date in a Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have an app which shows dates. I would like to print a date in the `F j` format if the year of the date is the same as the current year, and in `F j, Y` format if it is different. I would consider this to be presentation logic and would like to encapsulate this in template code, without modifying my views.

Ideally, I would like something like:

`{{ the_date|date:'F j' }}{% if the_date.year == now.year %}{{ the_date|date:', Y' }}{% endif %}`

The issue is that I cannot find a way of getting the current year in a way that can be used within an if tag. I know I could just include a `today_dt` in my template and compare against that. However, I am wondering if there is a way of not having to modify my views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use a custom template tag filte (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) Would look something like

```
import datetime

from django import template
from django.utils.dateformat import format

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def custom_date(date):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if date.year == now.year:
        return format(date, 'F j')
    return format('F j, Y')
```

then in your template

```
{% load custom_tags %}

{{ the_date|custom_date }}
```

Comment: That is one option which will work. I am curious if there is any place where the template has access to any "current" date. I was looking around the `request` object, but no luck.

Comment: there is a {% now %} default template tag, but that isn't useful for the use case you have, only for outputting the current date time. You could create a context processor so that it was sent to every single template render but it's not a very good practise.

Comment: Minor bug in the template tag code. The second rerun statement should read: `return format(date, 'F j, Y')`